# Using jQuery scrollTo() in multiple-page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, hyperlink

I'm using the jQuery `scrollTo()` function to go between different points in my client's site. So I'm using this code:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.scrollto/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.main-navigation a[href^="http://yoursite.com/#"]').click(function() {
      jQuery.scrollTo( this.hash, 1000, { easing:'swing', offset:-160 });
    });
  });
</script>
```

And it works just fine on the homepage.

But this is a multipage site. I need it in the navigation, so that when someone clicks on a link, the link scrolls to the proper portion of the page, plus the offset (as it has a fixed menu covering part of the page up). How can I incorporate this into my jQuery?

Comment: Why not just use [links to an anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/254/anchors-and-hyperlinks/1076/)?

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. And all that does is you click on the link, it takes you to the homepage, and it jumps to the point in the page, but no scrolling, no offset. So because there's a fixed header, it appears odd and off.

Comment: Then maybe use query parameters and handle them from the JS/jQuery from the page?